# Getting coordinates from Firebase to make annotations

Tags: swift, firebase, annotations, mapkit, core-location

I am currently trying to get my data from firebase and create annotations in my MKMapKitView. I believe that I am retrieving the data properly but not creating the annotations properly.

I think that because there are multiple users I cannot just set it up as a regular way of annotating.

```
   let   userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(userLatitude!), longitude: Double(userLongitude!))

                let userAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation();
        userAnnotation.coordinate = self.userLocation!;
                //userAnnotation.title = "Riders Location";
                map.addAnnotation(userAnnotation);

        }
```

I'll also add in how I am retrieving the users.

```
func retrieveUsers(){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let users = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.user.removeAll()
            for (_,value) in users {
                if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                    if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                        let userToShow = User()
                        if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String,
                            let userLongitude = value["long"] as? Double,
                            let userLatitude = value["lat"] as? Double


                        {
                            userToShow.fullName = value["full name"] as? String
                            userToShow.imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String
                            userToShow.userID = value["uid"] as? String
                            userToShow.userLongitude = value["long"] as? String
                            userToShow.userLatitude = value["lat"] as? String

                            self.user.append(userToShow)
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.map.reloadInputViews()

                //not sure if this is right
            }
        })
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Becca, are you getting any error messages? what do you actually see on your map? any other details for us to get a sense of what you think has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a hunch, but I think you are after a function like this - you were pretty close with you effort! NB - no semicolons in swift syntax.

```
private func addUserAnnotation(user: User) {        

    let userAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    let userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(user.userLatitude!), 
longitude: Double(user.userLongitude!))

    userAnnotation.coordinate = userLocation
    //userAnnotation.title = "Riders Location"
    self.map.addAnnotation(userAnnotation)

}
```

Call the function like this - let's say you want to add annotation for just the first user from your user array:

```
addUserAnnotation(user: user[0]) //addUserAnnotation(user[0]) also acceptable
```

Here is the OP's class for the user. I think this is also important

```
class User: NSObject {

    var userID: String!
    var fullName: String!
    var imagePath: String!
    var userLongitude: Double! // change from String!
    var userLatitude: Double!  // change from String!

}
```

Comment: I am receiving this as an error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'MKPointAnnotation'" Firebase saves all of the data as a string... Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries, let's run a test then to see if there's a problem casting to double from the user properties userLatitude and userLongitude.  How about just adding some decimal numbers in place there and seeing if an annotation is added to your map.  You can find suitable coordinates by doing print(user.userLatitude) and print(user.userLongitude) at the top of the addUserAnnotation function.

Comment: I am not getting anything when I try printing the user coordinates. Nor am I am able to plug in coordinates and have them work... I'll start there

Comment: Ok, so it seems there are problems in both retrieval of coordinates and showing the annotation.  what happens if you move the code out of addUserAnnotation and straight into `viewDidLoad()` with a self-specified coordinate (not involving the user class), does that plot an annotation?

Comment: I just spotted an inconsistency in that you declare your userLongitude/latitude as String in your User class but ask for a Double in your if let statements in your database retrieval above - this means that the following code where you create userToShow will not be executed. My recommendation is that in your User class to already declare userLongitude and userLatitude as Double so that we don't need to deal with that casting downstream when it is retrieved.

Comment: If you change those to type double, we will need to modify this as so: `let userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: user.userLatitude!, 
longitude: user.userLongitude!)`